# How do I find the minimum force to be applied to a block sliding in a incline such as it moves with constant velocity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

The figure shows a block over an incline. Find the minimum force that must be applied to the block so that the body of mass $m=2\,kg$ such as that body moves with constant velocity upwards in the incline. It is known that the coefficient of friction between the surfaces is $\mu = 0.3$ and the angle of the incline is $\alpha = 30 ^{\circ}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given on my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&21\,N\\
2.&23\,N\\
3.&18\,N\\
4.&20\,N\\
5.&2.2\,N\\
\end{array}$

I really need help with this problem. Initially I thought that I should decompose the force and weight. Which I assumed that from the figure the force is parallel to the floor which is the base of the incline.

By doing this and considering that the coefficient of friction (which I assumed that is static) this would be translated as follows:

$F\cos\alpha - \mu N = 0$

The normal or the reaction from the incline I found it using this logic:

$N- mg \cos\alpha - F\sin\alpha = 0$

$N= mg \cos\alpha + F\sin\alpha$

Inserting this in the above equation:

$F\cos\alpha - \mu \left(mg \cos\alpha + F\sin\alpha\right) = 0$

$F\cos\alpha - \mu mg \cos\alpha - \mu F\sin\alpha = 0$

$F \left( \cos\alpha - \mu \sin\alpha \right) = \mu mg \cos\alpha$

$F=\frac{\mu mg \cos\alpha}{\cos\alpha - \mu \sin\alpha}$

Therefore by inserting there the given information would become into:

$F=\frac{\frac{3}{10} (2\times 10) \cos 30^{\circ}}{\cos 30^{\circ} - \frac{3}{10} \sin 30^{\circ}}$

$F=\frac{\frac{6\sqrt {3}}{2}}{\cos 30^{\circ} - \frac{3}{10} \sin 30^{\circ}}$

$F=\frac{\frac{6\sqrt {3}}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{3}{10} \times \frac{1}{2}}$

Here's where simplification becomes ugly:

$F=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\frac{10\sqrt{3}-3}{20}}$

$F=\frac{60\sqrt{3}}{10\sqrt{3}-3} \approx 27.25$

Therefore in the end I obtain that value for the force. But it is nowhere near to the answers. Can somebody help me with this?. What could I had done wrong?. How could I simplify this?. Can somebody offer a FBD help for this problem?

Comment: What is the force needed for equilibrium?  That force is the minimum needed so the block moves upward at a constant velocity of zero feet per second.  There is no minimum force that will push the block upward at a constant positive velocity as there is no minimum positive velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Calling $\beta = \frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$ and projecting the forces along the incline and assuming the movement positive upwards,

$$
F\sin\beta - m g\sin\alpha = \mu\left(F\cos\beta+m g\cos\alpha\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

[Free Body Diagram of the mass 'm'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9NiQ.png)

From the vertical (with respect to the slope) forces, we get:
*N* = *mg$\cos θ$* + *F$\sin θ$*

So, by balancing the horizontal (with respect to the slope) forces, we get:

*mg$\sin θ$* + *f* = *F$\cos θ$* 
→ *mg$\sin θ$* + *μN* = *F$\cos θ$* 
→ *mg$\sin θ$* + *μ*(*mg$\cos θ$* + *F$\sin θ$*) = *F$\cos θ$* 
→ *mg$\sin θ$* + *μmg$\cos θ$* + *μF$\sin θ$* = *F$\cos θ$* 
→ *mg$\sin θ$* + *μmg$\cos θ$* = *F*(*$\cos θ$* - *μ$\sin θ$*) 
→ *mg*(*$\sin θ$* + *μ$\cosθ$*) = *F*(*$\cos θ$* - *$μ\sin θ$*) 
Dividing both sides by *$\cos θ$*, we get: 
→ *mg*(*$\tan θ$* + *μ*) = *F*(1 - *μ$\tan θ$*) 
∴ *F* = *mg*$\frac{\tan θ + μ}{1 - μ\tan θ}$

Now, substituting *θ* = *30°*, *m* = 2 *kg*, *μ* = 0.3 and *g* = 10 *ms<sup>2</sup>*, we get: 
*F* = $2*10\frac{\frac {1}{\sqrt{3}} + 0.3}{1 - 0.3*\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}$ 
→ $20\frac{0.57 + 0.3}{1 - 0.57*0.3}$ 
→ $20\frac{0.87}{0.829}$ 
→ $20*1.04$ 
→ $20.8$ 
~ 21 *N*